# Fit a linear transformation in python

Tags: python, statistics, scikit-learn, linear-algebra, linear-regression

I have two sets of vectors x_i \in R^n and z_i \in R^m

I want to find a transformation matrix W
such that W x_i approximates z_i,

i.e. I want to find W that minimizes:   sum_i || W x_i − z_i ||^2

Is there a Python function that does this?

Comment: How many of each do you have?  I think you're looking for least squares - is that right?

Comment: I have 5000 vectors of each. x_i have dimension 300, and z_i dimension 800. yes, it is least squares.

Comment: You're trying to use some mathematical formatting that Stack Overflow doesn't support at all... please make you question more readable.

Comment: It's not clear from your question - are you familiar with numpy?

Comment: no, it was a mistake to put numpy in labels

Comment: It is not lst square. Lst square will solve for a vector of parameters which will minimize the distance between outputs and vector of parameters "times" the inputs. 
Here the vector X remains the same for all components of Z ...(in lst sqaure you have a different couple (X,Z) each time to calibrate your model.). Just write the equations to see it!

Comment: Actually you are looking for a matrix `m x n` which each line `Wi` (it is a vector) is such to minimize the quantity `Wi.X - Zi`. There is an infinity of solution for each `Zi`.

Comment: I just want to know if there already exists a module that can do this, because it is a classical question. but it is not linear regression.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with this problem, but I would imagine it exists either in pandas or numpy.

Comment: Please next time, do not suppose quite randomly a solution like lst square, think about the problem. It can be misleading for the author of the question and for those who will read the comments, taking a wrong way ;)

Comment: @Mustafa Was your problem solved ? I'm trying to solve a similar problem and i'm still stuck.

Comment: Yes, my problem was solved by the answer: it's just the transpose of a linear regression problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [this kronecker product identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations) it becomes a classic linear regression problem. But even without that, it is just the transpose of a linear regression setup.

```
import numpy as np
m, n = 3, 4
N = 100  # num samples

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

W = rng.randn(m, n)
X = rng.randn(n, N)
Z_clean = W.dot(X)

Z = Z_clean + rng.randn(*Z_clean.shape) * .001
```

Using `Z` and `X` we can estimate `W` by solving argmin_W ||X^T W^T - Z^T||^2

```
W_est = np.linalg.pinv(X.T).dot(Z.T).T

from numpy.testing import assert_array_almost_equal
assert_array_almost_equal(W, W_est, decimal=3)
```

Comment: Hi,
Do you mind elaborating a little on this step :
`Z = Z_clean + rng.randn(*Z_clean.shape) * .001`

Comment: I generate the clean target `Z_clean` according to the model. Then I add noise (the line you are inquiring about does this) in order to show that the method works even if the data are slightly perturbed. The noise is Gaussian because a least-squares estimate implicitly assumes Gaussian noise.